# DataGrid break columns to fit window so no horizontal scrolls are needed

Tags: wpf

How can i break the DataGrid to fit the window so no horizontal scrolls are needed?
i tried to put it in a WrapPanel but it didn't work

i want to split it like this:

```
|A| |B| |C|
--  --  --
--  --  --
|D| |E|
--  --
```

Comment: That's not how a `DataGrid` works. If you want to wrap like that then you'll have to add each cell to the `WrapPanel` individually - which isn't going to be easy or scalable. Why don't you want scroll bars?

Comment: can another control do that?

Comment: It is quite difficult to achieve it. The idea is use **ItemsControl** with custom StackPanel as **ItemsPanelTemplate**. The custom StackPanel need to override MeasureOverride, ArrangeElements and ArrangeOverride to arrange as you want. It is quite time consuming.